# ctrl+h as Backspace in linux GUI apps

Tags: linux, keyboard-shortcuts

After doing some work in linux terminals, I got used to the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> shortcut acting like the <kbd>Backspace</kbd> key.

Now I want to use this shortcut everywhere (not just in terminal).

This is easily done in Windows via [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/), but I can't find a way of globally setting this behaviour on linux.

Most (GUI) applications do nothing after pressing the shortcut and some (I'm looking at you, Firefox) show a useless (for me) sidebar and screw the keyboard focus, which is a rather unpleasant slap in the face.

So, does anyone here know how can I globally map <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>h</kbd> to <kbd>Backspace</kbd> under X?

I tried to look at the xkb keymap files, but without success.

I'm using [Gnome](http://www.gnome.org/) and [Awesome](http://awesome.naquadah.org/) at the moment, but if it can be done regardless of the window manager, all the better :-).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(better late than never)

It can be done for gtk applications:

Locate or create ~/.gtkrc-2.0

add the following line:

```
gtk-key-theme-name = "Emacs"
```

restart your gtk-app (pidgin. firefox etc) and you will be able to use ctrl-h ctrl-w and ctrl-u for deletion

Comment: In Ubuntu I had to set "/desktop/gnome/interface/gtk_key_theme" to "Emacs" using gconf-edidor to make this work, but, yeah, it does.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The default behavior for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>h</kbd> is <kbd>Backspace</kbd> for `ASCII`-based systems and should not require (re-) definition.

Comment: But it still doesn't work like that under X window with most GUI apps like Firefox, Pidgin, etc.

Comment: That's a per-application redefinition that particular programs (wrongly) make.

Comment: Hmm... and is there a way of preventing that? Besides modifying the applications themselves, I mean.

Comment: From http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/kb/Keyboard+shortcuts - "Firefox does not provide any method of customizing keyboard shortcuts."

Answer (score 0):

After quite a bit of Google searching, I found

[XHKeys](http://wmalms.tripod.com/#XHKEYS)

which seems to be able to do quite that... There is a long manual there to, I only skimmed through that. So it's up to you to really verify if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks, XHKeys does allow for this kind of customization. The customization works fine for gui and terminal application but it works erratically for web applications within Firefox :/